# How to find a lot of elements that contains a certain text with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I would like to check if the browser is able to look for the presence of a lot of different elements that contains differents words.
I sometimes use this code in this cases:

```py
try:

    elemtwo = WebDriverWait(browser, 2, poll_frequency=0.1, ignored_exceptions=None).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), ' first example of text')]")))
    if elemtwo:
        break

except NoSuchElementException and TimeoutException:
    pass
try:
    elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 2, poll_frequency=0.1, ignored_exceptions=None).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'second example of text')]")))
    if elem:
        break

except NoSuchElementException and TimeoutException:
    pass
```

If I had 20 different words, what should I do in order to find them by writing as few as possible?
Let me explain better: I have for example a list of 20 words like this:

- police;
- apple;
- monkey;
- ecc...

What should I do to not write the same command `{browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), "one of the list's word")]")}` 20 times?

**FIRST EDIT**: Sorry, I did not specify that the above 20 words or texts are arbitrarily choosen by me, regardless of their relevance to the website.

Comment: We can do this with Java but not with Python

Comment: @Prophet : excuse me ! what do you mean by we can not do this in python ?

Comment: In my opinion, Prophet means that on python I have to write: browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), "police")]")         browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), "apple")]")         browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), "monkey")]") ecc....     and repeat the command for each word I am looking for,

Comment: why not store them in a list all police, apple and then use a loop and feed one by one to find_element

Comment: cruisepandey, I had a similar idea, but I can't make it concrete.

Comment: I mean Expected Conditions in Java accepting And and Or so you can wait for presence of one from several conditions as well as for all of several conditions, not just for single condition

Answer (score 1):

You can do **find_elements_by_xpath** instead of find_element_by_xpath and then iterate.

**EDIT** - Here is a code i wrote to iterate through the list of links on the page.

from selenium import webdriver

chromePath = "chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromePath)

url = "http://books.toscrape.com/"

driver.get(url)

elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")

for elem in elems:

```
print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods in Selenium

`find_element` and `find_elements`

**find_element :** - find element will return a single web element where as

**find_elements :** -  will return a list of web elements.

so instead of writing this

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), "a list's word")]")
```

n number of times then,

you can simply do

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), "a list's word")]")
```

**Note :** The xpath `//*[contains(text(), "a list's word")]` should represent multiple web elements in UI, otherwise you will end up with single web element if it happens to be.

Now I see that you are using Explict Wait so in that case,

you have a lot of options such as :

```
presence_of_all_elements_located
```

or

```
visibility_of
```

both of them will return a list of web element so when you do :

```
list_of_ele = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, 'some xpath')))
```

Now iterate it, or do anything what Python allows you to do with this list.

Read more here :

[Selenium - official docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

**Update 1 :**

```
list = ['apple', 'police', 'etc', 'something else']
counter = 0
for search in list:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/"+ list[counter])
    counter = counter  +1
```

Comment: I can't understand how to use your answer for my problem. Perhaps, if I tell you concretely what I want to do, you will probably understand better what I intend to do. In short, I am creating a scalper bot for amazon that must crash when it finds phrases such as: Disponibilité inconnue "," Bientôt disponible "" Currently not available "," Not available "," Available since "," Not available " , "Temporalmente sin stock"

Comment: For this reason, I am using {browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), "a list's word")]")}. In my case, the lists word includes the phrases I wrote to you in the previous comment.

Comment: @Michael : If I got you, please see above the updated 1

Comment: it is probably the solution I am looking for because, as I can see, your code tries to find the element's list
through the entire page

Comment: Despite this problem, your intuition helped me write the question better.